# Finding the caller activity from child activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities a parent and a child activity but the child activity is also triggered by another activity. Now I want to return result from this child activity to the Parent activity ONLY when the child activity is triggered from this parent activity.

Is there any way the child can find out the caller activity (so that it does some calculations only for that caller activity). Is there any way I can avoid this:

```
intent.putExtra("caller", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

I want this:

```
if (ParentActivity)
{  //do something and finish() }
if (AnotherActivity)
{  //do something more and finish() }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that by using [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) from the Parent activity that you chose to be the one handling the results.

> Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished.
>   When this activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be
>   called with the given requestCode. Using a negative requestCode is the
>   same as calling startActivity(Intent) (the activity is not launched as
>   a sub-activity).

Basically in the Parent activity you can do:

```
Intent intent = ...
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_UNIQUE_INT_CODE);
```

Then you have to define a method to handle the results which is [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == SOME_UNIQUE_INT_CODE) {
              // do something
         }
     }
```

Inside the child activity, you can set the result by using [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29). There are two variants of this method one of them gives you the possibility to pass in some data.

Please, read the documentation to find more about how to use it.

EDIT:

You can use: [getCallingActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) from the called activity to find which is the parent activity but that only works if you used startActivityForResult.

> Return the name of the activity that invoked this activity. This is
>   who the data in setResult() will be sent to. You can use this
>   information to validate that the recipient is allowed to receive the
>   data.
>
> Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it
>   did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes
>   a request code), then the calling package will be null.

Comment: Bro I guess u didnt understand my ques. I know how to get the result but I want to DETECT the caller/parent activity from the called/child activity. and I want to avoid placing intent.putExtra(..) from caller to the child to know which is which.

Comment: My bad, but you said:  Now I want to return result from this child activity to the Parent activity ONLY when the child activity is triggered from this parent activity.

Comment: I know every1 will suggest me using intent.putExtra(..) from caller but I just wanna know if its possible from within the called/child activity to detect its parents. ( how come a parents have to tell the child who r they...!!!)

Comment: I don't think that's possible :)

Comment: I actually found something that does it. By using  getCallingActivity() See my edit.

Comment: Sigh...In android world nobody is for nobody except for business...(the child can only know if its informed..)

Comment: I think what I proposed should do the job :)

Comment: Yes I think so, now can I do just- if (getCallingActivity() !=null ) then do somthing...?

Comment: That's not enough you should do an equality test on the ComponentName that is returned. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html You can test on the class name using getClassName()

if((getCallingActivity() != null) && getCallingActivity().getClassNam().equals("ParentActivity")) {}

Comment: This is not working bro - if((getCallingActivity() != null) && getCallingActivity().getClassName().equals("TdeeActivity")) 
I felt it wud work.....

Comment: Tanvir, try to debug your code by printing getCallingActivity().getClassName() in the LogCat to see what it is equal to. Also, did you start that activity using startActivityForResult(..)?